# Cannot deserialize value of type java.time.LocalDate from String

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, java-time

I have input json payload like below. My Entity Class ImportTrans  eventTime type currently is LocalDate . How i can format it to accept the json input format.

```
{
"eventId":"ep9_0579af51-4b5c",
"eventTime":"5/11/2022 5:50:58 PM",
"eventType":"Update"
}

public class ImportTrans implements Serializable {
@Id
private Long processId;// AutoGenerator
private String eventId;
private LocalDate eventTime;
private String eventType;
}
```

HttpMessageNotReadableException Bad request 400 error - JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "5/11/2022 5:50:58 PM":

Comment: That string doesn't represent a localdate, it represents a localdatetime. Are you sure this is rhe payload you want?

Comment: Yes , the payload is coming from external service . I dont have control over it . But i can change the entity to any type i want . Even i tried with localdatetime still its throwing error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your spring-boot version, if its >=2.2 , then below might work straight-away

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
..

@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
private LocalDate eventTime;
```

Comment: Nice. I too would consider changing to `LocalDateTime` so that we also pick up the time of day from the JSON input.